# In awk, why are "" and "\n\n" treated the same for the RS parameter?

Tags: linux, unix, awk

Here are the contents of the file:

```
Person Name
123 High Street
(222) 466-1234

Another person
487 High Street
(523) 643-8754
```

And these two things give the same result:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="\n"; RS="\n\n"} {print $1, $3}' file_contents
```

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="\n"; RS=""} {print $1, $3}' file_contents
```

The result given in both cases is:

```
Person Name (222) 466-1234
Another person (523) 643-8754
```

`RS="\n\n"` actually makes sense, but why is `RS=""` also treated the same way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They aren't treated the same.

- `RS=""` invokes paragraph mode in **all awks** and so the input is split into records separated by contiguous sequences of empty lines and a newline is added to the FS if the existing FS is a single character (note: the POSIX standard is incorrect in this area as it implies `\n` would get added to any `FS` but that's not the case, see https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2019-04/msg00029.html).
- `RS="\n\n"` works in **GNU awk** to set the record separator to a single blank line and does not affect FS. In all other awks the 2nd `\n` will be ignored (more than 1 char in a RS is undefined behavior per POSIX so they COULD do anything but that's by far the most common implementation).

Look what happens when you have 3 blank lines between your 2 blocks of text and use a FS other than `\n` (e.g. `,`):

```
$ cat file
Person Name
123 High Street
(222) 466-1234



Another person
487 High Street
(523) 643-8754
```

.

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{FS=","; RS=""} {print NR, NF, "<" $0 ">\n"}' file
1 3 <Person Name
123 High Street
(222) 466-1234>

2 3 <Another person
487 High Street
(523) 643-8754>
```

.

```
$ gawk --posix 'BEGIN{FS=","; RS=""} {print NR, NF, "<" $0 ">\n"}' file
1 3 <Person Name
123 High Street
(222) 466-1234>

2 3 <Another person
487 High Street
(523) 643-8754>
```

.

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{FS=","; RS="\n\n"} {print NR, NF, "<" $0 ">\n"}' file
1 1 <Person Name
123 High Street
(222) 466-1234>

2 0 <>

3 1 <Another person
487 High Street
(523) 643-8754>
```

.

```
$ gawk --posix 'BEGIN{FS=","; RS="\n\n"} {print NR, NF, "<" $0 ">\n"}' file
1 1 <Person Name>

2 1 <123 High Street>

3 1 <(222) 466-1234>

4 0 <>

5 0 <>

6 0 <>

7 1 <Another person>

8 1 <487 High Street>

9 1 <(523) 643-8754>

10 0 <>
```

Note the different values for `NR` and `NF` and different `$0` contents being printed.

Comment: If we set `FS=","` (as in the first example), I would have expected all of the contents of the file to be one single record, since there are no instances of `",\n"` (you said this is what POSIX does to single char FS, adds a \n) and it would end the records at EOF. Why are there two records?

Comment: How does supplying the `--posix` option make a difference? From what I read here: gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Options.html it just disables a bunch of gawk features to be compatible with POSIX. Is `gawk --posix` = `awk`? Why put another two examples with this option specifically? Also, this might be related, but could you clarify what the difference between "GNU awk" and "all awks" is? Searching does not yield anything useful.

Comment: @herophant "adding \n to the FS" doesn't mean changing `,` to `,\n`, it means changing `,` to `[,\n], i.e. **either** `,` or `\n` separates fields not `,` followed by `\n`. Adding `--posix` disables gawk features including multi-char RS and so `RS="\n\n"` then means `RS="\n"`. gawk, mawk, tawk, BSD awk, nawk, /usr/xpg4/bin/awk, and busybox awk (and I'm sure others) are all `awk` just like a 747 and an Airbus and a Learjet are all airplanes. So gawk is awk and gawk --posix is also awk.

Comment: POSIX is a standard that most awks adhere to as a minimum and some, e.g. gawk, provide additional extensions, just like there's some minimum standard for airplanes (e.g. the ability to take off and land!) but various airplanes can have different characteristics on top of that (props vs jets for example). Why did I add more examples? So you can see how gawk with it's default extensions enabled behaves vs how POSIX compliant awks (including gawk with it's extensions disabled) behave given both `RS=""` and `RS="\n\n".

Comment: I did all of these examples in both gawk and awk, and the results were exactly the same, so I'm not sure how gawk is different here. Does awk also not adhere to POSIX without the option `--posix`? You say: "RS="\n\n" works in GNU awk to set the record separator to a single blank line and does not affect FS." Does this mean that if you say RS="\n\n" somewhere in your BEGIN at all, awk (or whatever awk you are using) instead executes gawk? (since POSIX cannot deal with two RS chars)

Comment: @herophant I'm not sure what you're trying to say with "the results were exactly the same" - you can see in my answer how each invocation behaves, are you saying when you run the same commands you get different results than those I've shown? or are you saying that when you type `awk ...` you get the same results as with `gawk ...` and they match what's shown in my answer? If so then `awk` on your system is an alias for `gawk` - run `awk --version` and `gawk --version` to see that.

Comment: wrt `Does awk also not adhere to POSIX without the option --posix` - I already explained that. POSIX is a standard that most awk variants conform to. Some, e.g. gawk, have extensions and if you want to ensure you aren't writing code that relies on those extensions than you can run `gawk --posix` to disable the extensions and only be running with POSIX functionality so you can ensure that your script will be most portable to another awk.

Comment: wrt `Does this mean that if you say RS="\n\n" somewhere in your BEGIN at all, awk (or whatever awk you are using) instead executes gawk?` - no. Whatever awk version you call is whatever awk version you're going to run. If you write `RS="\n\n"` and you call an awk that is not gawk or you call gawk --POSX then that will be treated as if you had written `RS="\n"`. If you write `RS="\n\n" and you're running gawk withput --posx then RS will be treated as 2 blank lines as you intended. That's all. No magic involved. If

Comment: You're making this all way more complicated than it is - it's extremely simple: POSIX is a standard that almost all modern awks conform to. POSIX defines RS to be a single char and says if you use more than 1 char then the behavior is undefined so any awk variant can do whatever it wants with that. Gawk has many, many extensions one of which is mult-char RS. If you call `gawk --posix` then you are disabling gawk extensions, including multi-char RS, and so gawk will interpret `RS="\n\n"` the same way as every other awk I know of which means it will be treated as if you wrote `RS="\n"`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, awk and gawk are the same on my system. Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Because [POSIX awk specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) says so.

> If `RS` is null, then records are separated by sequences consisting of a `<newline>` plus one or more blank lines, leading or trailing blank lines shall not result in empty records at the beginning or end of the input, and a `<newline>` shall always be a field separator, no matter what the value of `FS` is.

Comment: FYI the POSIX standard is wrong in saying `no matter what the value of FS is` - a newline is only added if the FS is a single char. They've been notified, see https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2019-04/msg00029.html for background if you care.

Comment: @Ed thanks for the info. I'll leave my answer as it is though, since POSIX standard didn't fix it yet.