# How do I extract select paragraphs that contain a given keyword?

Tags: powershell, awk

In short: I'm looking for the PowerShell equivalent of the following `awk` command:

```
awk '/keyword/' RS='' ORS='\n\n' input.txt
```

My goal is to extract select paragraphs from text that contain a specific keyword - not just the lines that contain the keyword, but the whole paragraph.

The rule imposed on my text files is that every paragraph starts with a certain pattern (e.g. `Pa0`) which is used throughout the text only in the start of the paragraph. Each paragraph ends with an extra newline character.

For example, imagine I have the following text:

```
Pa0 
This is the first paragraph bla bla bla
This is another line in the same paragraph bla bla 
This is a third line bla bla 

Pa0
This is the second paragraph bla bla bla
Second line bla bla My keyword is here!
bla bla bla 
bla 

Pa0
Hey, third paragraph bla bla bla!
bla bla 

Pa0
keyword keyword
keyword
Another line! bla
```

My goal is to extract the paragraphs that contain the word `keyword`. For example:

```
Pa0
This is the second paragraph bla bla bla
Second line bla bla My keyword is here!
bla bla bla 
bla 

Pa0
keyword keyword
keyword
Another line! bla
```

Comment: I don't see what this does besides search for a word, and doublespace the output.

Comment: To use bash commands in powershell use `bash -c "command"`

Comment: Good point, @js2010: I've fixed the `awk` command, and I've also restored the OP's original problem description, which hopefully clarifies things.

Comment: @NekoMusume Note that the standard `awk` utility (on Unix-like platforms) has nothing to do with `bash`, and that can you can invoke `awk` directly from PowerShell - the command in the question works as-is.

Comment: Note: `RS=''` (setting `RS`, the record separator, to null / the empty string) is a POSIX-mandated, and therefore _portable_ `awk` idiom for breaking the input into paragraphs by one or more blank lines;  by contrast, `RS='\n\n'` - i.e., a _multi-character_ record separator - is only supported by _some_ `awk` implementations, such as GNU `awk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To offer a more concise and faster alternative to [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62328699/45375).

```
(Get-Content -Raw input.txt) -split '\r?\n\r?\n' -match 'keyword'
```

<sup>Note: Regex `\r?\n` matches a single newline in a platform-neutral manner - it matches both CRLF and LF-only newlines. If you only have LF-only newlines, `\n\n` will do.

To restrict matching to the *start* of a paragraph, use `'^keyword'`.</sup>

- This will only return the matching paragraphs, as intended, as an *array* of multi-line strings, which, for instance, you can process one by one with the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/ForEach-Object) cmdlet.
- Note that if the final matching paragraph also happens to be the last paragraph overall in the file, it may have a trailing newline.

---

Documentation links:

- The [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-Content) cmdlet.
- `-split`, the [string splitting operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split)
- `-match`, the [regular-expression matching operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match)

Answer (score 1):

Read the file into chunks with `Get-Content -Delimiter`, then filter against your keyword with `Where-Object`:

```bsh
$paragraphs = Get-Content .\input.txt -Delimiter "`n`n" |Where-Object { $_ -like '*keyword*' }
```

---

If you're working on porting existing automation from a unix-like operating system to Windows, you may find that the convention of using carriage return + newline for line breaks will mess with your script.

In that case, either use `` "`r`n`r`n" `` as your delimiter, or go with [mklement0's excellent regex-based solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62328779/712649) (which will take both newline formats into account)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Oh I see, RS="\n\n" will only work in gnu awk.  I was also looking at example 3 here:  [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)  So the way the question read before

```
awk '/keyword/' RS="\n\n" ORS="\n\n" input.txt
```

wouldn't work in standard awk.  I was trying it in osx.  [In awk, why are "" and "\n\n" treated the same for the RS parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57851531/in-awk-why-are-and-n-n-treated-the-same-for-the-rs-parameter/57856237#57856237)

Comment: Yes: `RS=''` (setting `RS`, the record separator, to null / the empty string) is a POSIX-mandated, and therefore _portable_ `awk` idiom for breaking the input into paragraphs by one or more blank lines;  by contrast, `RS='\n\n'` - i.e., a _multi-character_ record separator - is only supported by _some_ `awk` implementations, such as GNU `awk`. However, your answer now has little to do with the original question, so I suggest removing it.